# SQL - Check constraint with values from another table and in legit format

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I have a table `Orders(OrderID, OrderName, ClientCity, ClientNumber, ClientAddress, FullAddress)`. I have a task to make the `FullAddress` be in the following format: `ClientCity/ClientAddress-ClientNumber)`.

I have a query but I don't know if it's correct: `ALTER TABLE Orders ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK(FullAddress LIKE City'/'ClientAddress'-'ClientNumber)`?

Comment: Right, my bad. I added a mysql tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I right, you want to check if the FullAddress value corresponds to the other client fields ?

This will not fill the FullAddress for you, only check if you have correctly filled it.

To check the FullAddress:

```
ALTER TABLE Orders 
    ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK(FullAddress = CONCAT(City,'/',ClientAddress,'-',ClientNumber))
```

Not clear why you use `LIKE` instead of `=`

Comment: Thank you. I use `LIKE` because my professor never taught us about `CONCAT` but he was brave enough to give a task with something he didn't teach us.